# Cannot find image name and extension from encode url

Tags: php, urlencode

I have a question would like to ask you, it was about php. My problem when I tried to use php function to extend image extension from an url which has form below :

http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/i_qpu5lXHddZgNaEbzEEz1CaArLCHEmVNuhwVOuDUl0aIyZHuez3s4Uf878y1n9CqB5rld2a7GSAoWzoMgrC

so , for above url is made by Google which is not show use the file name and extesion name. of course I have try to use this below function but still not work :

$image_name = basename($url);

could anyone help me.

Comment: You cannot get the information from this URL only. You can request the image, read only the HTTP headers and look for the `Content-type` header. Alternatively, if you are saving the image anyway, you can use [`finfo_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) to recognize it.

Comment: Both the content type as file as the filename are provided using the headers when making the request. [`Content-Disposition: inline;filename="unnamed.png" Content-Type: image/png`](https://requestable.pieterhordijk.com/pKCuvc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are downloading the image, you can get the extension using [finfo_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php).

---

Else you can look for the content type in the headers sent by the server using [get_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)

*example code*

```
<?php
$url = 'http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/i_qpu5lXHddZgNaEbzEEz1CaArLCHEmVNuhwVOuDUl0aIyZHuez3s4Uf878y1n9CqB5rld2a7GSAoWzoMgrC';

print_r(get_headers($url));

?>
```

*sample output*

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [1] => Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    [2] => ETag: "v1"
    [3] => Expires: Wed, 22 Apr 2015 09:10:30 GMT
    [4] => Cache-Control: public, max-age=86400, no-transform
    [5] => Content-Disposition: inline;filename="unnamed.png"
    [6] => Content-Type: image/png
    [7] => Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2015 09:10:30 GMT
    [8] => Server: fife
    [9] => Content-Length: 20365
    [10] => X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    [11] => Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,p=1
)
```

Comment: could you tell me about array number 5? why there is no name of the file?

Comment: @samphors the server returns the name of file as unnamed.png . try opening it in your browser and saving it .